# Python extract information from list of objects

Tags: python, list, extract

The following is a list of 'Position' objects.

```
[Position(account='U3953931', contract=Forex('AUDUSD', conId=14433401, localSymbol='AUD.USD', tradingClass='AUD.USD'), position=100.0, avgCost=0.70995),
 Position(account='U3953931', contract=Stock(conId=211651685, symbol='URA', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='URA', tradingClass='URA'), position=-20.0, avgCost=23.06155705)]
```

How can I extract the *-20.0* value given that I'm looking for the position within the URA symbol?

I managed to make this:

```
positions[1][2]
```

That returns the *-20.0*

Comment: What is the actual type of `position`? How is the `__repr__` of the class related to its actual attibutes? Have you tried `positions[1].position`?

Answer (score 0):

probably not very elegant but this works:

```
for i in range(0, len(positions)):
    if positions[i].contract.symbol == Stock_Symbol:
        print(positions[i].position)
```